# Releasing CoreData objects with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

Since I moved to ARC two months ago I discovered that I have problems with releasing objects.
I am now using interments to try and get a grasp on how to do this, but am struggling a bit.

I have a function that counts NSManagedObject. Unfortunately, there is a bit of logic involved, so I actually need to fetch the objects (instead of just counting).

The MOC is running on the main thread, so is used for everything that is visible.
The count happens on the first view (unread badges) and the objects themselves are not used on that view (so are not needed anymore after the count)

The functions used are these:

```
- (int) getUnreadCount:(DOCategory*) category {
    @autoreleasepool {    
        NSFetchedResultsController* items = [self getUnreadArticlesForCategory:category onlyForCounting:YES];           
        if([[items fetchedObjects] count] == 0) return 0;          
        int counter = 0;
        long commonId = [[[[items fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] commonId] longValue];
        bool read = [[[[items fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] read] boolValue];

        for(DOArticle* article in [items fetchedObjects]){
            long articleCommonId = [article.commonId longValue];
            if(articleCommonId == commonId) {
                //if([article.read boolValue] == true) read = true;
            } else {
                if (!read) {
                    counter++;
                }
                read = [article.read boolValue];
            }

            // If this was the last item, decide if an etra needs to be added
            if([[items fetchedObjects] indexOfObject:article] == [[items fetchedObjects] count] - 1){
                if(!read) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            commonId = [[article commonId] longValue];
        }           
        items = nil;          
        return counter;
    }
}
```

And the function called:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) getUnreadArticlesForCategory:(DOCategory*) cat onlyForCounting:(bool) onlyForCounting {
    NSPredicate* basePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(((ANY groups.validTime > %@) && (ANY groups.active == YES)) || (ANY groups.universal == YES)) && (site.active == YES) && (removed == NO) && (language.enabled == YES)", [NSDate date]];

    NSPredicate* countPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY categories.countUnread == YES)"];
    NSPredicate* nonCountPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(read == NO)"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = nil;

        NSPredicate* catPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY categories == %@)", cat];
        if (onlyForCounting) {

            predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                          @[basePredicate, catPredicate, countPredicate]];
        } else {
            predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                       @[basePredicate, catPredicate, nonCountPredicate]];
        }

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:_cacheName];

    NSFetchedResultsController* aFetchedResultsController = [self createFetchedResultsController:_cacheName sectionString:nil sortBySection:NO];
    [aFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [aFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];
    [aFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchLimit:0];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"commonId" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"language.order" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor2, nil];

    [aFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *fetchError;    
    if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&fetchError]) {
        NSLog(@"Fetching data error: %@", [fetchError localizedDescription]);
    }
    return aFetchedResultsController;
}
```

In instruments I use the 'Zombies' function, and see that:

```
Graph    Category   Live Bytes  # Living    # Transient Overall Bytes   # Overall   Bytes Allocated (Net / Overall)
0   DOArticle_Article_  10.88 KB    174 0   10.88 KB    174 <XRRatioObject: 0x7fe843844f20>  %0.00, %0.00
```

Looking at one of the objects it gives:

```
#   Event Type  ∆ RefCt RefCt   Timestamp   Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   Malloc  +1  1   00:04.140.423   CoreData    _PFAllocateObject
1   Retain  +1  2   00:04.140.771   CoreData    _faultBatchAtIndex
2   Retain  +1  3   00:04.140.785   iDomsPortalDev  -[DOArticleController getUnreadCount:]
3   Release -1  2   00:04.141.596   iDomsPortalDev  -[DOArticleController getUnreadCount:]
4   Retain  +1  3   00:04.141.599   iDomsPortalDev  -[DOArticleController getUnreadCount:]
5   Release -1  2   00:04.141.614   iDomsPortalDev  -[DOArticleController getUnreadCount:]
6   Release -1  1   00:04.156.411   CoreData    _releaseStaleBatch
7   Release -1  0   00:04.298.640   CoreData    -[_PFArray dealloc]
```

So it seems that the object should be released (since I put in the @autorelease code), but it still says 'living' in the 'Allocations Summary', so I am not so sure what to do. As mentioned, the objects are not used anymore (or shouldn't) so should all be released and gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that the default behaviour when Zombies is enabled?

When zombie detection is enabled, objects are never destroyed and therefore staying alive, even if the retaincount is back to zero. That's because the zombies function is especially to inspect issues with overreleased objects.

In other cases i would disable zombie detection or just use the 'Allocations' (or 'Leaks') template. That will give you more accurate info on the actual memory usage, allocations (and living/transient objects).

Comment: Oooh, yes, that makes sense! I will try that later this afternoon! I did notice getting different results with both templates, and that does explain it I think. I haven't really used instruments for some time (shame on me!) and with the move to ARC there is a whole new world opening up.